# Generating CSV file with optional columns (based on condition)

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

We have a use case where we want to generate a CSV file out of records (can be ~500k). The records are fetched from a db via pagination and converted to a bean collection. Thereafter, the beans are written as rows of CSV file.

Sample bean:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class EventRecord {
    private String eventDate;

    private String eventId;

    private String eventContextId;

    private String localeId;

    private String description;

    private String amount;
}
```

The problem is that out of the fields in the bean, depending on condition some field might need to be omitted from the CSV.

Example: String csvColumns = getCsvColumns() can return:

- "eventDate,eventId,eventContextId,localeId,description,amount"

or

- "eventDate,eventId,localeId,description,amount"

These are actually the required columns for the CSV file.

We can assume that these columns can vary depending on client requirement of CSV file, and column list will be available in input request.

Queries:

- How can we achieve customised csv writing with optional columns (e.g. eventContextId is omitted in second example)

We have looked into [ColumnPositionMappingStrategy](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/ColumnPositionMappingStrategy.html), and have tried to write via [StatefulBeanToCsv](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/StatefulBeanToCsv.html), however we are encountering "NullPointerException" in the `StatefulBeanToCsv.write()`, which is not apparent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have found Apache Commons CSV to be much easier to use and it also follows the standard in RFC 4180. OpenCSV can be made to follow the standard with extra custom code but while it looks like it would be easier to use, it's just more complicated and non-standard. Just my 2 cents.